# Take a folder containing PDF files as input, and output for each PDF how many pages it contains

Tags: windows, pdf

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 or 10 that can take a folder containing PDF files as input, and output for each PDF how many pages it contains.

Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) you could use this command:

`exiftool -PageCount -ext pdf /path/to/pdfs/files/`

If you need to recurse into subdirectories, add `-r`.  You can list multiple directories for the command and it will process them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [cpdf](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdflib-binary) (Microsoft Windows/Linux/Mac OS X) and [Iterate over all files in a directory using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138497/395857).

To print the number of pages in one PDF:

```
cpdf.exe -pages "my file.pdf"
```

In Microsoft Windows, to print the number of pages in all the PDF files the current folder contains in  [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
for /r %i in (*.pdf) do cpdf.exe -pages "%i"
```